# Update 2nd column based on access from first column

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to put the current date & time (on an individual row basis) in column K of my google docs spreadsheet, if either of column I or J is changed.  This is my first attempt at using google scripts.

I've located a function that will do the time (and I'm hoping I can figure out how to do the date), but I don't know how to check for changes in cells, and update other cells.  So for example if row 10 column I or J changes, row 10 column K should get the current date & time.

```
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var timeStamp = d.getTime();  // Number of ms since Jan 1, 1970

  // OR:

  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString(); // "12:35 PM", for instance
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer to use `GMT-8`. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a shot - it uses string formatting to put the current date in the proper format (you can adjust as you need). One important thing to note: regardless of what you do here, the value will be displayed according to whatever formatting you have specified in the spreadsheet itself. Therefore if you don't do anything, the result is going to look like the traditional datetime representation. If you want it to appear in the format you specify, you can do two things: 1.) convert the entire column to text using the spreadsheet's **Format** menu; or 2.) (my choice) prefix the value you write with a `'`, which will essentially turn it into a string (that is what is done in the code below). Hope this helps.

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // This was "MySheet" for me - change to whichever sheet you want to test
  if( s.getName() == "MySheet" ) {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    // Check if the column is either I or J
    var currColumn = r.getColumn();
    if( currColumn == 9 || currColumn == 10) {
      // If so, set dateCell = the current row at column J
      var dateCell = s.getRange(r.getRow(), 11);
      // Format the current date into datetime format (adjust to display how you want)
      var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "MMM-dd-yyyy h:mm a");
      // Set the cell
      dateCell.setValue("'" + dateTime);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Yeah was able to find a "manual".  Now my date string looks like this:

Comment: @AB How are you looking for your date string to appear?

Comment: Yeah was able to find a "manual".  Now my date string looks like this:     var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "MMM-dd-yyyy h:m TT");           I'm using MMM which is supposed to be - month name, short, but it doesn't work and I'm using TT which is supposed to be AM/PM but it doesn't work  (continued)

Comment: and I'm using h:m which is supposed to give me single digit hours & minutes, and i do get 1 digit except seconds is always double zero instead of blank.  Any further ideas?  thank you

Comment: @AB Updated the answer. The basic issue has to do with the format in which the spreadsheet itself is displaying the number. The easiest workaround I know of is to prefix the new date string with an apostrophe, which will treat it like a string and thereby prevent the spreadsheet from trying to format the datetime value in a particular way. Hope this helps.

Comment: If I use MMM or TT, there is no output whatsoever.  I assume you mean to put the apostrophe in the string like this: "'MMM-dd-yyyy h:m TT"  That doesn't seem to make a difference, there's still no output.  To get output, I have to eliminate both TT and change MMM back to MM.  So they don't work individually, and they don't work together either.  Just broken?

Comment: @AB Sorry, forgot to mention that you need to add `a` instead of `TT` (see my update example for the format string). It all works fine for me with the adjustments, so I'm sure we can get it working for you too :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19419/discussion-between-a-b-and-rocketdonkey)

Comment: @AB I dropped an adjustment into our chat conversation - let me know if that works for you (I think we're close to closing this one out :) ).